# OpenCV drawing an ellipse from the camshift algorithm output.

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using camshift to track tennisballs and drawing an ellipse around the tennisball once its found. However, every so often I get this error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (box.size.width >= 0 && box.size.height >= 0 &&       thickness <= 255) in ellipse, file /home/eanders/src/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/core/src/drawing.cpp, line 1678 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /home/eanders/src/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/core/src/drawing.cpp:1678: error: (-215) box.size.width >= 0 && box.size.height >= 0 && thickness <= 255 in function ellipse
```

I'm assuming that the camshift method is returning a RotatedRect object that somehow isn't of the correct dimensions for an ellipse to be drawn inside of. Any ideas how to correct this? Code is as follows. Thanks in advance guys.

```
Rect trackWindow = Rect(p1, box);
///employ camshift algorithm
RotatedRect trackBox = CamShift(backproj, trackWindow, TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1 ));
ellipse( image, trackBox, Scalar(255,255,255), 3, CV_AA );
ellipse( backproj, trackBox, Scalar(255,255,255), 3, CV_AA );
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as if the algorithm was not able to track the object.
It would be great to know why, but for now I would check the dimensions of the rotated rect.
That is clearly what the assertion is complaining about.

Comment: Yah, this is possible. I decided it was easiest to just dump the ellipse and put a small circle at the center coordinates of the RotatedRect since i'm most interested in that center point anyway. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Does the RotatedRect have a useful position?
I **guess**, that the algorithm can't track the object and therefore returns a default Rect (dimensions of 0x0 and maybe a position of 0,0). Therefore you might draw these points at a wrong position...

Comment: Yes, the RotatedRect seems to be following the object for the most part. My work around seems to work fairly well.